# Dynamic imports in typescript broken either in tests or in webpack runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, jestjs

I have a TypeScript project that uses webpack to compile the bundle. I'm using Jest + ts-jest for testing.

I'm trying to get dynamic imports working but can only seem to get it working either in the tests or the bundle, but not both. In this case the library I'm trying to dynamically import is `zxcvbn` but I imagine this might apply to any library.

E.g. I have a script:

```
const result = import('zxcvbn').then(zxcvbn => zxcbn('foo'))
```

When testing this, the test runs fine. It also compiles the bundle with no problems. However when  run in the browser I get:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): zxcvbn is not a function

So to fix this I added `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to my `tsconfig.json` and changed the import line to:

```
const result = import('zxcvbn').then(({default: zxcvbn}) => zxcbn('foo'))
```

Now the browser runtime works fine but the test fails with

> TypeError: zxcvbn is not a function.

I also tried using a extended `tsconfig.test.json` for the tests with `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false` but this results in a compilation error:

> Property 'default' does not exist on type  '(password: string, userInputs?: string[] | undefined) => ZXCVBNResult'

Any idea how to fix this? I'm currently not using Babel, just the TypeScript compiler + Webpack for bundling.

Comment: I'm not sure yet how to solve this, but a couple of pointers on the reasons why you run into this issue:
1. when you use ts-jest, your tsconfig is overriden with `module: commonjs`, meaning the `import()` statement is transpiled to a simple `Promise.resolve(require('zxcvbn'))` call. and since `zxcvbn` is a commonjs module, the first argument of `then` callback is the `zxcvbn` function itself.

2. from the webpack side of things, since import() is designed to work with es6 modules only, webpack will wrap a commonjs module in an object with the `default` key.

Comment: That's useful info. It seems like I can get around the issue if I make an intermediate module that imports the `xzcvbn` library using normal es6 import syntax and then re-exports it. I can then `import(./myLocalZxcvbn').then(...`.